# Adding attachment to email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to create a button that saves a worksheet in pdf format, Attaches to a new mail and send it. 
i can create the pdf, save the pdf on my desktop, create and e-mail. but the PDF is never attached. Where am I going wrong?

```
Dim pdfName As String
   pdfName = PONumberLabel.Caption  ' add PO number on label to a variable

     ' create pdf and save to desktop

       ChDir "C:\Users\roanderson\Desktop" ' selects directory to save
       Sheet4.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True, _              
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        Filename:="C:\Users\roanderson\Desktop\" & pdfName  ' directory put t

    ' sending email for approval
    Dim xOutApp As Object
    Dim xOutMail As Object
    Dim xMailBody As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    xMailBody = "Please approve PO Number" & " " & PONumber & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Cost Centre:" & "   " & costcentre & vbNewLine & _
              "Description:" & "   " & description & vbNewLine & _
              "Currency:" & "   " & POCurrency & vbNewLine & _
              " Total:" & "   " & total
                  On Error Resume Next
    With xOutMail
        .To = "Ross.anderson@work.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "PO Number " & PONumber & " " & "Approval"
        .Body = xMailBody
        .Display   'or use .Send
        .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\roanderson\Desktop\" & pdfName
        .VotingOptions = "Accept;Reject"




    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xOutMail = Nothing
    Set xOutApp = Nothing
```

Everything works except attaching pdf to email.

Comment: Comment out `On Error Resume Next` - that's just hiding errors.

Comment: Maybe Changing `.Add` line to `.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\roanderson\Desktop\" & pdfName & ".pdf"` may help .... Because I think your variable `pdfname` isn't giving you complete name with format.

Comment: Perfect Thankyou.. Mikku all sorted! I knew it would be simple!! ‍♂️

Comment: @Mikku, can you put it up as an answer for the future?

Comment: Sure ...... @RossAnderson ... Accept the Answer if it worked for you :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the Statement

`.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\roanderson\Desktop\" & pdfName`

To

`.Attachments.Add "C:\Users\roanderson\Desktop\" & pdfName & ".pdf"`

As it seems like pdfname does not have the full name with Extension.